# Is it possible to override hbase-site configuration per tenant?

Tags: configuration, hbase, multi-tenant

As I understand from the [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_configuration_files) (formatted by me)

> **hbase-site.xml**
>
> The main HBase configuration file. This file specifies configuration options which override *HBase’s default configuration*. You can view (but do not edit) the default
> configuration file at docs/hbase-default.xml. You can also view the
> entire effective configuration for your cluster (defaults and
> overrides) in the HBase Configuration tab of the HBase Web UI.

To what I could figure out there would be just a single `hbase-site.xml` configuration across the cluster. But what I am interested to know, is if there is a way to define/override the configuration per tenants created in the cluster?

***Use case***: We have a multi-tenant HBase setup at work, wherein we need to onboard another client with certain fixed configurations defined in `hbase-site.xml`. Now, we are evaluating if we can live with the existing cluster and a new tenant OR should we be creating a new cluster for the new client?